# Terminal starts fast, but takes time to get ready

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, prompt, konsole

I'm on Kubuntu 20.04 and it's been a while since I've noticed that even though the konsole terminal starts fast after I enter the shortcut, it takes some seconds for the command prompt itself to appear on-screen so that I can start typing. It *usually* happens just on the first time I launch it on a session, but it may happen again some time later on.

Does anyone have a clue on what could be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a terminal window, `echo $SHELL` will tell you which shell you're running.  Read the `man` page for that shell. It will have information about "Startup Files" or "`INVOCATION`". For example, if `echo $SHELL` tells you `/usr/bin/bash`, read `man bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, maybe this is what's happening to you as well if you also use `node`:

After temporarily moving my `~/.bashrc` file to another folder and restarting the system to identify if the lag was being caused by my user configs or if it was system-wide, the prompt was immediately ready when I launched the terminal. Then I found out that the `nvm` install adds some snippets to `~/.bashrc`, and this is what causes the prompt loading lag in terminal.

After some digging I found a solution [here](http://broken-by.me/lazy-load-nvm/).
I hope it helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

As [Alex Braga](https://askubuntu.com/users/1010360/alex-braga) mentioned before, there must be something in your `~/.bashrc` that causes the delay.

First action is to add `set -x` at the beginning of this file, so that you can discover what's causing this delay.

In my case the culprit was the `kubectl completion bash` command.

Hope it helps!